# Saving and reusing register in C64 assembler?

Tags: assembly, 6502, c64

I have this code:

```
        jsr cls
        ldx #$00    ;loads 0 into x
        stx tmp     ; stores x in tmp
        ldx #<scr1
        ldy #>scr1
printToScreen
        stx zpb+0
        sty zpb+1
        lda (zpb),y
        ldx tmp.       ; loads x from tmp
        beq done
        sta screen_start,x
        inx
        stx tmp        ; stores new x in tmp
        bne printToScreen
done
        rts

tmp = $C8
zpb = $fb
scr1 byte 'some text'
byte 0
```

I want to create routine which prints a string to the screen. The arguments are the address of the string and the X register, which is used as a counter. Since X is used inside the function as well I'm storing its value in the tmp variable.

But this code prints nothing. I'm totally new to assembly, so probably I don't understand how this is supposed to work.
Please see code comments. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

```
            jsr cls
            ldy #$10    ; loads $10 into x as a string length
            lda #<scr1
            sta zpb+0
            lda #>scr1
            sta zpb+1
printToScreen
            lda (zpb),y
            sta screen_start,y
            dey
            bne printToScreen
            rts
```

I would do that way. To be honest I didn't test the code I've written above. I've changed it the way I think it should be done.

Concerning your code:
It is not needed to overwrite zpb and zpb+1 in every loop iteration.
You forgot to set Y index register before you do "lda (zpb),y" - and probably it should be zero. After "ldx tmp" you don't compare it wth anything (should be cpx #something) so as default you compare it with zero (beq done) and cpu quits the program because X==0. So your program writes one byte somewhere in the memory and just exits.

Comment: It looks like your `dey` `bne printToScreen` may never print the 0th byte.  It's been a while since I used `bpl`, but maybe change `bne printToScreen` to `bpl printToScreen`, but that also means .Y must start off at < #$80 bytes?

Answer (score 1):

Is .X supposed to be the *length* of the string that is being printed?

Your current code:

```
printToScreen
    stx zpb+0
    sty zpb+1
    lda (zpb),y
    ldx tmp.
    beq done
    sta screen_start,x
    inx
    stx tmp
    bne printToScreen
```

What I *think* you are trying to do is:

1. Pass the address of the string in .X and .Y
2. Store this in `zpb`
3. Fetch the bytes using indirect addressing at zpb and store them to the screen at `screen_start`

A couple of problems:

- `lda (zpb),y` is the correct *addressing mode*, but you never initialize the .Y register. So the .Y register at the first call is actually using the most significant byte of the address you passed to begin with
- The combination of `inx` `stx tmp` `bne printToScreen`.. When you do the `inx` and `bne` you are saying "increase .X, save it, and if it is not equal to zero, branch to `printToScreen`".  But that effectively looks like you are trying to copy 256 bytes.
- Notwithstanding never initializing .Y, you also never change it, so it will effectively always get the same byte pointed to (indirectly) by `zpb`.
- You are initialzing .X with #$00 and storing it in `tmp`, but that really doesn't need to be done with what I think you are trying to do.
- If .X is supposed to be the *length* then you aren't actually defining that anywhere...you are effectively doing this for 256 bytes (unless that's what you want?)
- You keep storing .X and .Y in `zpb`, but that precludes you from actually using .X and .Y

That said, what I *think* might work for you is:

```
    jsr cls     ; assuming this is a routine to clear the screen
    ldx #<scr1
    ldy #>scr1
    stx zpb+0
    sty zpb+1
    ldy #$00
printToScreen
    lda (zpb),y
    beq done
    sta screen_start,y
    iny
    bne printToScreen
done
    rts
scr1 .asc 'some text'
    .byt 0
```

What this will do is:

- store the location of `scr1` in `zpb`
- loop through `scr1` and store it at `screen_start`, and end if:

  - the current byte is the 0 byte (it checks this before doing the actual copy); *or*
  - .Y becomes zero (again, after initialization)